# pass data to form filed in django templae

Tags: django, forms, templates

How can I pass data to form fields in django templat ? , for example I have below code in my project:

```
<td class="col-3">
  {{form.number|as_crispy_field}}
</td>
```

Can I use

```
<td class="col-3">
  {{form.number}} = 10
</td>
```

in django template ?

Answer (score 1):

@mosi -

```
<td class="col-3">
  {{form.number}} = 10
</td>
```

No, you cannot use this. If you are planning to pass data from views to template then do something like this
Let's say you have a form something like this
forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # your logic here
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

template.html

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.name }}
  {{form.email}}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

OR
Simply

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, if you want to set initial values to your form in template
Lets say you have the following

```
 class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,initial='test')
```

Then in your template you do something like this

```
 <form method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ form.name.value }}">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Now, in case of an UpdateView where data is pulled in dynamically from the Database based on let's say product id. The following is just an example

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
         exclude = (
        "created_by",
        "slug",
    )


class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    # specify the model you want to use
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = "catalog/product/update_product.html"

product_update.html
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p}}
                  

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

                </div>
            </form>

              Or


 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ form.name.value }}">
 <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="{{ form.description.value }}">  
 .........          
                      
    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: thanks for excellent answer. but I want pass data in django form only , because the one field get different data  in any situation

Comment: In fact, I want fill the form field form hidden input by variable value

Comment: @mosi-   <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="{{ form.name.value }}">

Comment: @SDRJ- by this solution, Can I send a custom value to productForm() in views.py ?, Is it possible take an error in compile codes ?

Comment: @mosi- Not from the views but you can add custom values in the forms.py. The view just passes the forms to the template. Its job is to delegate. Don't do too much processing in views.

Comment: @SDRJ- thanks for help, your all answer was very good